# Huge Django Session table, normal behaviour or bug?

Tags: django, django-sessions

Perhaps this is completely normal behaviour, but I feel like the `django_session` table is much larger than it should have to be.

First of all, I run the following cleanup command daily so the size **is not** caused by **expired sessions**:

```
DELETE FROM %s WHERE expire_date < NOW()
```

The numbers:

- We've got about 5000 unique visitors (bots excluded) every day.
- The `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` is set to the default, 2 weeks
- The table has a little over **1,000,000 rows**

So, I'm guessing that Django also generates session keys for all bots that visits the site and that the bots don't store the cookies so it continuously generates new cookies.

But... is this normal behaviour? Is there a setting so Django won't generate sessions for anonymous users, or atleast... no sessions for users that aren't using sessions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit of debugging I've managed to trace cause of the problem.
One of my middlewares (and most of my views) have a `request.user.is_authenticated()` in them.

The `django.contrib.auth` middleware sets `request.user` to `LazyUser()`

Source: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py?rev=14919#L13 (I don't see why there is a `return None` there, but ok...)

```
class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'."
        request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
        return None
```

The `LazyUser` calls `get_user(request)` to get the user:

Source: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py?rev=14919#L5

```
class LazyUser(object):
    def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
        if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
            from django.contrib.auth import get_user
            request._cached_user = get_user(request)
       return request._cached_user
```

The `get_user(request)` method does a `user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]`

Source: [http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py?rev=14919#L100](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py?rev=14919#L100)

```
def get_user(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    try:
        user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
        backend = load_backend(backend_path)
        user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
    except KeyError:
        user = AnonymousUser()
    return user
```

Upon accessing the session sets `accessed` to true:

Source: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py?rev=14919#L183

```
def _get_session(self, no_load=False):
    """
    Lazily loads session from storage (unless "no_load" is True, when only
    an empty dict is stored) and stores it in the current instance.
    """
    self.accessed = True
    try:
        return self._session_cache
    except AttributeError:
        if self._session_key is None or no_load:
            self._session_cache = {}
        else:
            self._session_cache = self.load()
    return self._session_cache
```

And that causes the session to initialize. The bug was caused by a faulty session backend that also generates a session when `accessed` is set to true...

Comment: I know this answer was written a long time ago but I'm seeing the same problem. The explanation seems to make sense but is there a fix? Thanks!

Comment: For me the fix was to make sure sessions weren't generated when they ware not really used. One of my middlewares set the session to `accessed` in all cases causing it to generate on every pageview for every bot.

Comment: Hmm... must be a different problem from mine then. I tried creating a brand new django 1.4 app and the django.contrib.auth.views.login seems to cause a new session to be saved if the user is anonymous and hasn't visited previously. I created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098142/django-session-created-in-database-when-login-page-loaded. Would be great if you could take a look. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible for robots to access any page where you set anything in a user session (even for anonymous users), or any page where you use `session.set_test_cookie()` (for example Django's default login view in calls this method)? In both of these cases a new session object is created. Excluding such URLs in robots.txt should help.

Comment: The problem was that in one of the middlewares I was using the sessions to detect if some cookie had to be set. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)
+1

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I wrongly set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in `settings.py` without understanding the exact meaning.

Then every request to my django service would generate a session entry, especially the heartbeat test request from upstream load balancers. After several days' running, `django_session` table turned to a huge one.

Answer (score -3):

Django offers a [management command to cleanup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#cleanup) these expired sessions!

Comment: As I've said in my original question, I am _not_ talking about expired sessions. I run a daily cleanup command already (not the Django version since that one dies long before you reach this amount of sessions).